# Performance of inserting to big table while checking for duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table that contains a varchar(100). I am trying to populate it with 1 billion unique records. I have a stored proc that takes a table type parameter containig 1000 records at a time and inserts it into the table while checking no duplicate exists. After about 50 million the performance goes down. I tried sharding the table and using the sql table partitioning with balanced distribution but no gain was observed.

How can i build this solution in sql with reasonable performance?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is incomplete. Please show the table definition, along with all its indexes, if any, and the code of your SP that checks for duplicates.

Comment: You could create a unique index using `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` and then just insert those rows, and don't check at all.

Comment: Inserting rows in batches of 1,000 of a time using a TVP doesn't sound very optimal. You could use the bulk insert API and insert into the table directly together with @horse's suggestion.

Comment: setting ignore_dup_key to on and using the bulk insert api helped a little but it's still slow once it reaches 100 million. does adding more memory help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try de-duping the data before you put it into the database, then disabling the unique key while inserting so you don't have to deal with rebuilding it as you go.

Comment: I am generating new pins in big batches and inserting them to the DB.I don't want to insert duplicate pins.